# What does "furnish" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> You **furnish** the Girl, we furnish the home! [The Goat (1921 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goat_(1921_film))

What does first "furnish" mean in the sentence? And what is meaning of the sentence generally? 
Is it an amphibology?: You provide the girl, instead of make a gift for her, we provide your home furniture. I think in that way because in the last scene of movie Buster Keaton puts the girl on his shoulder (like a property of exchange) and goes through store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a play on the various meanings of "Furnish"

As the slogan of a shop it might imply:

> To make a happy family you need a bride and a nice home. If you provide the girl to be your wife, we can sell you furniture to make your home nice.

An old-fashioned attitude to the role of women in the home, but common enough in the 1920s. You wouldn't see such a slogan today!

Keaton interprets this as "If you give us a girl..." to give the visual joke of him carrying a girl on his shoulders. His misunderstanding is the joke.

(note furniture is nearly always treated as *uncountable*, so "a furniture" or  "furnitures" are nearly always mistakes, you can use "pieces of furniture" if a plural is essential)